# Change padding/inset of image within JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

How do I make the distance between the icon and the text less/smaller?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setIconTextGap`

*To reduce gap by 1 pixel:*

```
button.setIconTextGap(button.getIconTextGap() - 1);
```

*To increase by 1 pixel:*

```
button.setIconTextGap(button.getIconTextGap() + 1);
```